# Test have poor results when using BatchNorm

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

I'm researching Resnet with my teacher and we did some change. After modification, the final loss is MSE, Training steps are 10000. 
I use `AdamOptimizer` and `tf.layers.batch_normalization`. Training result has good performance.

But when I test, set `training=False`, the performance is awful.

I have searched many possible situation.

```
updated_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(updated_ops):
        lead_paras = optimizer.minimize(lead_loss, global_step=counter_paras)
```

I always have this code, it's not an answer. And many other answers all couldn't solve my problem.

The model is like this:

```
inputs = conv1(inputs)
inputs = residual_block1(inputs) #some conv layer with residual
inputs = residual_block2(inputs)
inputs = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=inputs,
                                       axis=3,
                                       momentum=0.95,
                                       epsilon=1e-5,
                                       center=True,
                                       scale=True,
                                       training=is_training)
inputs = tf.nn.relu(inputs) # the size is [batchsize, 16, 16, 32]
T1 = inputs[:, :, :, 0:16]
T2 = inputs[:, :, :, 16:32]
label1 = tf.zeros(shape=tf.shape(T1), dtype=tf.float32)
label2 = tf.ones(shape=tf.shape(T1), dtype=tf.float32)
lead_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(T1-label1))
nolead_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(T2-label2))
loss = lead_loss+nolead_loss
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
updated_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(updated_ops):
    lead_paras = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=counter_paras)
```

like this.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B1iv.png)

I want `T1` approach 1 and `T2` approach 0.The training result is what I need.

I would be very appreciate if someone can help solve the problem.

Comment: You minimise 'lead_loss' in your last line, why not the whole loss 'loss'?Btw is this a regression or classification problem? If you like T1 to be 1 and T2 to be 0, you could simply handle those as class labels instead of continuous values.

Comment: @Tinu Thanks for your comment, you're right and I've edited code.  Actually it's an idea about classification, but now we want to control the  feature map, for example, feed class 0-4 images, we want to control  them only active in 16 feature maps like T1. This code simply implements the important part of idea, also caused problem like question mentioned.

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused here. You said you want `T1` to be 1 and `T2` to be 0, but for the `lead_loss` comparing T1 and `label1` you pass all zeros to `label1` which is exact the opposite of what you like to see. The same with `T2` and `label2`.

Comment: Further you said you like to control the feature map. Feature maps are usually associated with some kind of shape you like to recognize in your input, but you want the feature maps 0 to 15 of `inputs` to be all 1 and feature maps 16 to 31 be all 0. What kind of feature maps is that? What do you like to achieve when you say you want to "control" the feature map?

Comment: @Tinu omg my code is wrong, I'm sorry. About feature maps, maybe I can't explain it clearly. Inputs are 32x32x3, after first residual block it became 32x32x16, after second it will be 16x16x32. Suppose there are 2 class, control means I want class 1 flow past 0-15 and class 2 flow past 16-32. When class 1 flow past 0-15, I want 16-32 to be 0 to achieve "control". Class 2 vice versa. As for why I want T1 to be all 1, it's a simple test, I will change that in future. Thanks for your reply, if you have other questions, I'm very pleasure to answer.